# fileno cast FILE to descriptor C

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Is there a way to cast a variable of type int (file descriptor) into type FILE in C ? I have an open pipe fd and I want to use the functions which expect FILE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast it, but you can call [`fdopen(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fdopen/), which does exactly what you want:

> ```
> FILE *
> fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode);
> ```
>
> The **`fdopen()`** function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, *fildes*.  The mode of the stream must be compatible with the mode of
>        the file descriptor.  When the stream is closed via **`fclose(3)`**, *fildes* is
>        closed also.

Comment: Thanks Carl, so would fdopen end up making any system calls on the fd, or would it simply return a FILE stream ?

Comment: @user1944224, that's probably implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX systems, you can use [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fdopen.html) to construct a `FILE *` that refers to a file descriptor.